# How to add different icons around the login template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, templates, authentication

I am working on a normal login page. I would like to add different icons around the username and password text box.I have added a picture below. I am working on core UI template with Angular 4.

I could not able to get the sequence right.

```
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="card-group mb-0">
      <div class="card p-4">
    <div class="card-block">
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
          <form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-4">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: with "different icon" do you mean change the icons?

Comment: Ummmm in the username field, you want some differents icons inside this <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span> tag?

Comment: i mean around it..,i will redo the picture and will show the idea what i mean

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the icon, then choose your icon here:

http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icons/

and just change the class

```
<span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="icon-user"> </i></span> //Here

<span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="icon-lock"> </i></span> // andHere
```

Comment: no i know that..,i meant to add different icons outside of the login and password text box..like around it